# Sequelize include with association name vs. with model name

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

In sequelize doc, it mentioned that you can use include with model name, e.g.`const users = await User.findAll({ include: Task });`, and you can use include with association name, e.g.`User.findAll({ include: { association: 'Instruments' } }); // Also works`. I am wondering if there is a difference between them.

Background is that, I usually use include with model name, but I had to use include with association name because one of table is has two associations referring to the same table. Use model name will cause a multiple alias error. So I am wondering is there a difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already found out the model name does not guarantee a match to a certain association: only if you have one without alias. The association name works like a pair of a model name + an alias:

> association: The association you want to eagerly load. (This can be used instead of providing a model/as pair).
> So you can use interchangeably:

```js
User.findAll({ include: { association: 'Instruments' } })
```

or

```js
User.findAll({ include: { model: 'Task', as: 'Instruments' } })
```

Comment: Is there a performance difference between with/without alias, provided there ain't no multiple alias issue?

Comment: No diffrence at all. It affects only what alias will be for this table in SQL query. You can try both cases and compare generated SQLs.